# Is there any merging procedure for multiple scenes taking from RGB-D to avoid noise?

Tags: computer-vision

To avoid the noise as much as possible, I'm planning to take multiple scenes from RGB-D then try to merge them ....

so is there any research papers , thoughts , ideas , algorithms or anything to help

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE.  On this site, we want you to ask only one question per question.  Also, we expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, and to show us in your question what research you've done.  This is not a place to outsource your work to someone else.  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  Also, questions about specific products or hardware items (e.g., kinect v1 or v2) are off-topic here -- see our [help/dont-ask] -- but questions about general techniques or algorithms are potentially OK.  I encourage you to edit your question to improve it.

Comment: @D.W.  Thanks alot , is this good , after editing :)

Comment: I think this is *way* too broad for a single question. Community votes, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one technique is known as [super-resolution imaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-resolution_imaging).  There's a rich literature on the subject, at least for RGB images.  You could check Google Scholar to see if there has been any research on super-resolution for RGB-D images (e.g., from 3D cameras such as Kinect, Intel RealSense, etc.).